# Oracle TO_DATE está convertendo errado as datas a partir do dia 07/01/2020

Tags: oracle

A função TO_DATE do banco de dados Oracle está fazendo a seguinte conversão de forma errada:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As duas linhas estão exatamente iguais, só mudei o 7 para 8.
Não faz sentido (para mim), o Oracle converter certo a data da terça-feira e errar a da quarta-feira.
Não tem horário de verão nem nada...

Consulta:

```
SELECT 
  to_date('20200108 000000', 'YYYYMMDD HH24MISS') D1, 
  to_date('20200107 000000', 'YYYYMMDD HH24MISS') D2
FROM dual;
```

Comment: Só para ter certeza que realmente não tem horário de verão nem nada, qual horário ele está mostrando no resultado? Se você mudar a hora para 120000, o que acontece?

Comment: FIZ NO MEU AMBIENTE SELECT 
  to_date('20200108 000000', 'YYYYMMDD HH24MISS') D1, 
  to_date('20200107 000000', 'YYYYMMDD HH24MISS') D2
FROM dual;

D1       D2     
-------- --------
08/01/20 07/01/20

Comment: No sql fiddle também retornou o resultado correto: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a931c6/1

Comment: Deve ser algo relacionado ao meu ambiente. Obrigado, pessoal. Não consigo mudar a hora pra 1200000. @VictorStafusa Na primeira coluna, mostra 00:00:00, na segunda mostra 23:00:00

Comment: Verifique qual timezone está definido para sua instalação.

Comment: Como faço isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O servidor do meu cliente estava com relógio configurado para o horário de verão e ficou com esse erro pois em 2020 supostamente teríamos horário de verão no Brasil. Imagino que tenha acontecido por ser um Windows Server antigo e não ter atualizado as tabelas referente o horário de verão.

Ajustando o relógio resolveu tudo.

O erro em si eu acredito que tenha sido gerado pelo driver da aplicação, e não pelo Oracle.